# Dust stuck on Laptop Screen

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair, cleaning, laptop-display

The image u can view, is of my laptop screen, on which the dust is stuck and does not come out easily. The dust from keyboard keys over the time when laptop kept in bad position, the dust sticks on the screen. If anyone has encountered the same issue and has been successfull to take out the dust, please share me the methods to do it.

[image]

Comment: What image can we view? How is the dust "stuck"? What do you mean by "dust from keyboard keys over the time when laptop kept in bad position"?

Comment: The link was not getting added, you can view it now..

Comment: Use a screen cleaner?

Comment: I did, but it clears the finger prints and light dust which I clean regularly(the light dust), and this one is stuck firmly. and it comes out of the keyboard. and it does look bad many a times.

Comment: I have seen this before on devices, and in my experience it just wipes off...unless of course you actually caused physical damage to the screen...but the way these screens are built (I have taken many a apart) it shouldn't be very easy to get dust between the glass and the actual display...

Comment: It is the dust, emitted from between the keyboard key spaces. and its stuck on screen as firm.

Comment: This isn’t (just) dust. Keyboard and trackpad (and the dust) have caused abrasions on the screen. It is physically damaged.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a stronger cleaner, or to put the screen in a horizontal position and leave it with the cleaner for an hour, 2 or more until it desolves the dust properly, than pass on the screen with a proper cloth without breaking the screen.

Comment: I will surely try this first thing next morning, and will let u know then.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clean with the brush cotton impregenated with anti static spray.This will work